# How to deploy from a Developer Sandbox into Production

Tags: deployment, sandbox, change-set, developer-org

I used a Developer Sandbox that was created on developer.salesforce.com. I've been building on it for a while and recently purchased my own Salesforce instance. I was miffed when I realized the Developer Sandbox did not have a Change Set option in Setup. I assumed I would be able to connect the two and deploy one to the other or there would be a way to create my Production org off of the Developer org I've been building on. However, I have not found anything online.

Has anyone encountered this? Does anyone have any ideas on a solution?

Comment: You can use `Force.com IDE` or `ANT migration tool` or `Workbench` for deploying meta data between unconnected orgs.

Answer (score 4):

ANT, Force.com IDE and Workbench have a pretty steep learning curve. So it might take some time for you to get going. Those are really good tools but also complex tools.

If you want to get started and deploy quickly I would an online tool of it there are many with a free trial (I use [GearSet](https://gearset.com/), I do not know if I am allowed to write that here, if not I will remove it).

Those tools can connect to different environments compare and help you built the package.

Comment: Disclaimer: I work at Gearset. I second Gearset! The free trial is unrestricted and runs for 30 days, and you can sign up in about 10 seconds without needing to give us any payment information or anything like that. We also have great support, so if you have any questions just leave a message in the in-app chat and we should be able to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use ANT migration tool to do this. You can refer the below link to get more information about it.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/meta_development.htm

Comment: Okay. I'll give this a go.

Answer (score 0):

As your orgs are not connected, you won't be able to use change set to deploy metadata from the developer org to another unconnected org. Change sets are supposed to be used only when you have connection between the two orgs.

You can use any of the below mentioned options to deploy code from developer org to production or any sandbox.

- [ANT Migration Tool](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/meta_development.htm)
- [Workbench](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000315117&language=en_US&type=1)
- [Force.com IDE](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.eclipse.meta/eclipse/ide_pro_deploy.htm)